# Do all finite-dimensional division algebras appear as Wedderburn factors of rational group rings?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $D$ is a division algebra that is finite-dimensional over $\Bbb Q$, does there exist a finite group $G$ such that one of the factors in the Wedderburn decomposition of $\Bbb Q[G]$ is a matrix ring over $D$?

(Note that the answer with general base field is no, as there are countably many finite groups and each group algebra has only finitely factors in the Wedderburn decomposition, so the division algebras which appear as Wedderburn factors are countable, thus any field with uncountably many finite extensions is a counterexample)

Comment: The results of the paper https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022314X73900437/1-s2.0-0022314X73900437-main.pdf?_tid=27376ff0-078c-4d78-b2ce-55f6a779d7d1&acdnat=1527733086_bd9fed07387630af217f5d342eedaa89 would seem to indicate that not all appear.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg this answers the question, thanks!

Comment: A standard reference for this topic is Yamada, _The Schur subgroup of the Brauer group,_ LNM 397, Springer (1974), [doi 10.1007/BFb0061703](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0061703).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The subgroup of the Brauer group generated by (and in fact, consisting of) such division algebras is called "the Schur group". Brauer-Witt theorem asserts that it is given by cyclotomic algebras, so the answer is negative.
I learned this [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869385713646/1-s2.0-S0021869385713646-main.pdf?_tid=61bee0b0-68b9-4270-85a3-6874a46e8b87&acdnat=1527752129_4d7a4ad2e44b41e4e0aa67c40f5ad85a).